# Font Awesome & Bootstrap not working correctly In Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

After last two updates on Google Chrome I have a problem with rendering of icons on Font Awesome. Before everything worked correctly, and all icons loaded.

[image: FontAwesome]

When I hovered any icon on table row and all other show up too.

Font Awesome css file is after the bootstrap css

```
@import 'bootstrap.min.css';
@import "font_awesome/font-awesome.min.css";

<i class="icon icon-ban-circle"></i>
```

- Font Awesome 3.2.1
- Bootstrap v2.2.1

Comment: can you provide me a link to the website ? I need it for inspecting element for debugging purpose, because I've been using latest bootstrap and font awesome in updated chrome and there are no problem at all

Comment: The site is on a local server, and I can't get access to it.

Comment: Use any Free Hosting such as www.000webhost.com always for this kind of purpose and also make use of www.jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2):

You may be experiencing the same bug as google fonts described here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336476

My workaround (until google releases v35 (canary)) is to have jquery automatically repaint the body like this:

```
$(function() { $('body').hide().show(); });
```

... after the page is loaded (or ready). Fortunately that does not make the page flash.

Good luck!

Comment: God that's one nasty workaround .. but it works. I also noticed that Chromium's font rendering is next to random on Linux. I can load the same page 5 times and 2 of them will not have the same font line-height / kerning. I guess OCDs should stay away from typography.